# Reading object returned from "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table"

Tags: node.js, sqlite, better-sqlite3

```
let rows = db.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table").get();
```

Returns the object

```
{ 'COUNT(*)': 2 }
```

I am not sure how to read that as

```
console.log(rows.COUNT(*));
```

Returns

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Comment: do you use any ORM?

Comment: Not intentionally unless there is some implemented in the better-sqlite3 library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { 'COUNT(*)': 2 }

Since `COUNT(*)` is a key. You can access it directly by using [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
console.log('No of rows ', row['COUNT(*)']); //logs 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I am actually really surprised I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is

```
Object.values(rows);
```

It will return a length 1 array with just the number

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: This is a worse solution that Sridhar's because it is an array instead of just the count